# JQuery Sortable: Over/Change events fired on mouse move

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to bind to the over and change events when initializing sortable, but it seems like they are both being triggered every time I move the mouse while dragging.

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("change");   
      },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("over");   
      },
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

In this example (http://jsfiddle.net/brandonrose/7mdUN/1/) , "change" and "over" are logged to the console every time the mouse is moved while dragging.

Comment: What is the question exactly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to resize my sortable elements when the change and over events fire, however they are being fired everytime I move the mouse while dragging and therefore that code is running multiple times. According to the documentation, Change is supposed to be triggered "only when the DOM position has changed" and Over is triggered "when a sortable item is moved into a connected list", which is not the case.